# How do I foldr a list of type Double?

Tags: haskell, double, fold

I have some code I am writing and I need to fold a list of doubles, however, even this simple line of code gives me errors I dont understand, namely:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’
            with actual type ‘t0 [t1] -> [t1]’
Probable cause: ‘foldr’ is applied to too few arguments
In the expression: foldr (+) [3.3, 1.4, 5.5]
In an equation for ‘foldDoubles’:
    foldDoubles = foldr (+) [3.3, 1.4, 5.5]
```

for a simple example of:

> foldDoubles = foldr (+) [3.3, 1.4, 5.5]

examples for integers are the in the same format so I dont understand why there would be "too few arguments", do I need to do some kind of conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Probable cause: ‘foldr’ is applied to too few arguments

It's because `foldr` is applied to too few arguments.  Observed:

```
foldr (+) [3.3, 1.4, 5.5]
--     one  two
```

But:

```
:type foldr
Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
--              one            two  three
```

You are missing an argument of type `b`.  In this case you appear to want a sum so perhaps you'd like to start your fold using zero as the accumulator:

```
foldr (+) 0 ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it.. was looking at the haskell wiki and their first example is `fold (+) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` which is a bit misleading I guess

Comment: @MarcusRuddick `fold` is not `foldr`.

Comment: @MarcusRuddick That would still be wrong, the typical definition of `fold`  from `Data.Foldable` does not take a function parameter.  Where is this "haskell wiki".  Google has similar code as you show on the one-off haskell-lang.org site (different from haskell.org, which is usually what people mean by "the haskell wiki") but the -lang site seems to have deleted their wiki.  If you can point out the resource then we can work to fix it.

Comment: Ah, it says explicitly "a hypothetical function".

Answer (score 2):

The `foldr` function has type `Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b` which includes includes three arguments (`(a -> b -> b)`,`b`,`t a`) while you've only included two arguments. We can rewrite `foldDoubles` to hold our computed fold for the single hardcoded list by adding a base case of type `b` to fix this mistake:

```
foldDouble = foldr (+) 0 [3.3, 1.4, 5.5]
```

But let's look a bit further. Instead of hardcoding the list `[3.3, 1.4, 5.5]`, we can make a general purpose function that accepts a list and returns it's sum (this is just the sum function):

```
foldDouble xs = foldr (+) 0 xs
```

Which we can use on general lists just like our Prelude-defined sum function:

```
ghci>> foldDouble [3.3, 1.4, 5.5]
10.2
```

Next, we can eta-reduce this go get a slightly cleaner form:

```
foldDouble = foldr (+) 0
```

Lastly, there's a handy function `foldr1` that allows us to get rid of our base case (the last element in the list is presumed to be the base case instead). Using this function, we can get rid of the `0`:

```
foldDouble = foldr1 (+)
```

Comment: thank you, I just posted the hard coded version as an example... actual code is more complex and is indeed passed a varable list of doubles